# How can I hide my Parse.com API keys?

Tags: android, parse-platform, proguard

I develop a project with **parse.com** api. I use `api key and client key`

I use proguard to improve my app security if anybody can try decompile **.apk**

But in my app there is a `API KEY` and `CLIENT KEY`. How can I hide them or if anybody see those keys what happens?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can go through all sorts of machinations to obfuscate your Parse client key and app ID, but ultimately they're always going to be available to a clever person intent on discovering them. That's why protecting your data with proper ACL configurations is key. The suggestion of doing more in your Cloud functions is also a good idea if you want to hide details of your business logic which, if coded in your Android app, could be reverse engineered.

Answer (score 0):

You should always assume those keys will become known, and secure your classes in Parse accordingly using Roles and ACLs.

For extra security use Cloud Functions that have extra security logic in them.

Comment: thanks for answer but I do not understand clearly please give an example , my keys are in my main class so I do not understand how can I use acls to hide keys